# EditText value to Long

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to get value out of EditText field but I'm surely miss something here because it keeps getting the default(finnaly) value only.
Please help, I'm stuck with this for hours. Thank you.
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Long delay;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delay_in);
    try {
        String textStr = text.getText().toString();
        delay = Long.parseLong(textStr);
        //delay = Long.valueOf(textStr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        delay = 4000L;
    }
    SwapPicsActivity.delay=delay;

}
@Override
protected void onStop (){
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
}

public void takePicture(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class );
    startActivity(cameraIntent);
}
public void browseFile(View view) {
    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(this, BrowseFileActivity.class);
    startActivity(browseIntent);
}


}
```

and the layout:

```
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/delay_in"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:hint="Transition time (ms) :"
    android:editable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: That is the expected behaviour, `finally` is the final block of code that is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally block always works. So that change your code like that

```
EditText text= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delay_in);

    try {
        String textStr = text.getText().toString();
        //delay = Long.parseLong(textStr);
        delay = Long.valueOf(textStr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        delay = 3000L;
    } finally {
        //sth log
    }
```

[Doc is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Comment: Thank you, you're right that finally wasn't suppose to be there, right.But it still fails to read that value

Comment: Share the full source code pls. Did you debug the code ?

Answer (score 0):

> miss something here because it keeps getting the default

Sure you do -> The finally block **always** executes when the try block exits.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

So if you want to set defaults in case of troubles parsing user input, set `delay = 3000L;` prior entering `try/catch` block.

Comment: Thank you, you're right that finally wasn't suppose to be there, right.

Comment: It gets the text value from layout, if any, but not the user input, so probably is a layout thing

Comment: how come? Unless ID `delay_in` is used more than once it should point to EditText. Do you have other elements using `delay_in` id?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it worked with a listener, thanks everybody

```
  text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delay_in);
  text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int    count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            delay = 3000L;
            try {
                SwapPicsActivity.text=text.getText().toString()+"_";
                String textStr = text.getText().toString();
                delay = Long.parseLong(textStr);

                //delay = Long.valueOf(textStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            SwapPicsActivity.delay=delay;

        }
    });
```